# Anchor tag redirects to invalid url

Tags: java, spring, apache, anchor

This may be Stupid question. But i have no idea what is going. Following URL is example which is i have configured to redirect in my customer application.

```
<a href="http://cpolo.in/admin/about-us" class="btn_a medium_btn bottom_space">
```

I just using spring mvc project. Rarely when user click this URL it directly goes to following URL.

```
http://cpolo.in/admin/login
```

My security configuration is

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .access("hasAnyRole('SUPER ADMIN','ADMIN','STAFF')").and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/orderdetails")
            .usernameParameter("user").passwordParameter("pass").and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf().and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and()
            .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/login");

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll().and()
            .csrf().disable();

}
```

I have been using Spring MVC, Java 8 and Apache 8 server. What could be my mistake.

Comment: The admin controller is probably set up to require authentication for all of it's actions.  If you intend the "about-us" to be globally accessible, you'll need to add an exception.  http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/check-authentication-using-spring-mvc-and-handler-interceptor/

Comment: Can your share your security configuration file

Comment: I have updated the code with security configuration. Please let me know anything needed further